# Python Qt: Check visibility of widget / isVisible always return false

Tags: python, qt

I'd like to save the visibility state of a QDockWidget, when the dialog is closed. Even though, the widget is visible, isVisible will return false. 
What to do?

Using Python (2.7 in my case)

Comment: When are you saving this? Take care to do this before the dialog is actually closed. For example overwrite the done(int) or setVisible(bool) function of the dialog and save the state before calling the base implementation.

Answer (score 2):

*This might be the problem:*

Maybe you call isVisible() from an onClose()-function. Means, your Widget **was** visible, but is not anymore, when you finally call the isVisible() function

*Solution*

**Call isVisibleTo([ParentWidget])**. This will give you the visibility value relative to e.g. your QMainWindow.